# StackOverflowException when adding a row to a datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

Using recursion to build up the hierarchy.

This recursion works fine in windows server 2003 + IIS6 but throwing exception in windows server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.0

Here is the code snippet:

```
Public Sub Expand(ByVal SE_Index As Int64)

    Dim row As DataRow

    If aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).Visable = True Then
        aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).Target_Row = gvCurrent_Row_Number
        gvCurrent_Row_Number = gvCurrent_Row_Number + 1

        Try
            row = dtExpand.NewRow
            row("SE_NO") = aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).SE_No
            row("Selection_Index") = aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).Selection_Index
            **dtExpand.Rows.Add(row)**--->>>throwing error "stackoverflow"

        Catch ex As StackOverflowException
            If (ex.Message.Contains("Column 'SE_NO, Selection_Index' is constrained to  be unique.")) Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            row = Nothing
        End Try

        ' expand this SE's children  -  first
        If aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).Child > 0 Then
            Expand(aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).Child)
        End If
    End If

    ' expand this SE's Siblings  -  second

    If aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).Sibling > 0 Then
        Expand(aryHierarchyData(SE_Index).Sibling)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont think it is because of IIS and windows server. I think it is because of data. In [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.80).aspx) it is clearly stated that "**The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains too many nested method calls. This class cannot be inherited.**
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Stackoverflow problem could be solved using thread.
Call expand() under recursivethread function.

Private Sub RecurseThread(totalSeCount As Long)
 For iIdx = 1 To totalSeCount
    If aryHierarchyData(iIdx).Target_Row = 0 Then
    dtExpand.Clear()
    dtExpand.AcceptChanges()
    Expand(iIdx)
  End If
Next iIdx
End Sub

Dim t As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf RecurseThread, 1024 * 1024)
t.Start(totalSeCount)
t.Join()
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is depending on computer memory and Framework. It has nothing to do with IIS and windows server.

**The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains *too many* nested method calls. This class cannot be inherited.**[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I tried your code with some changes. I alter above statement according to my experience

Framework 4.0
**The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains *7573* nested method calls. This class cannot be inherited.**

Framework 2.0
**The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains *7038* nested method calls. This class cannot be inherited.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Am using windows server 2008 R2 ,IIS 7.0 and .NET 4.0.Without changing code,what changed need to be brought in computer memory or framework.We have upgraded application from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0

Comment: Well i did not tried with windows server 2008 R2, IIS 7.0 and .NET 4.0. Well i think what you have to do is to increase the stack size May be this article could help you [http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx)