# Stackoverflow Exception and the recursive methods

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

Why does these the application on the top does not throw a stack overflow exception ? what's up with the recursive method ? I understand that the bottom example creates a deep call stack so it throws the error. But the first example do we use the same space in the memory or does the garbage collector help us.

```
class ProgramErrorFree
{
    static void Main()
    {
       while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
        }
    }
}

class ProgramStackOverFlow
{
    static void Recursive(int value)
    {
        // Write call number and call this method again.
        // ... The stack will eventually overflow.
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Recursive(++value);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Begin the infinite recursion.
        Recursive(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why does these the application on the top does not throw a stack overflow exception ?

Why do you expect it to? From [MSDN: StackOverflowException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows *because it contains too many **nested** method calls*.

Your stack never gets deeper than two frames:

- `ProgramErrorFree.Main()`
- - `Guid.NewGuid()`
- - `Console.WriteLine()`

Whereas your second program the stack frames keep getting stacked:

- `ProgramStackOverFlow.Main()`
- - `ProgramStackOverFlow.Recursive()`
- - - `ProgramStackOverFlow.Recursive()`
- - - - `ProgramStackOverFlow.Recursive()`
- - - - - `ProgramStackOverFlow.Recursive()`
- - - - - - `ProgramStackOverFlow.Recursive()`

And so on, until you run out of stack space.

I think you expect a rapid succession of `Guid.NewGuid()` to "overflow" the stack, but that's not how that works. See Eric Lippert's blog [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) and further for more information about what the stack is and what it's used for.

See also [Running out of ValueType stack space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301703/running-out-of-valuetype-stack-space) for how to run out of stack space without recursion.

Comment: Real nice answer. Thanks for linking that Eric Lippert blog post.