# MSBuild: error MSB3073: "*Undefined*..\..\vc\bin\EditBin.exe"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, command-line, msbuild

I receive an error when I attempt to execute MSBuild on the commandline:

> error MSB3073: The command "call "*Undefined*....\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x86\r
>   error MSB3073: "*Undefined*....\vc\bin\EditBin.exe"

I am executing the following command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\Users\myuserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MySolution\MySolution.sln" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Mixed Platforms"
```

**NOTE:**

- I am using VS 2012
- Configuring system variables is disabled on my machine.
- I am attempting to automate a build process. As a result, this is why I am choosing the command prompt versus VS Command Prompt tools.

Comment: That's not MSBuild doing this, it is a borken post-build event in your project.  You'll have to fix it, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089197/17034) for an example.

Comment: Your comment resolved my issue. Please submit this as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you add this as an answer?