# Cannot increase stack size Visual Studio 2013 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, stack-overflow, stack-size

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community version to write a C# project.

My program parses HTML using HtmlAgilityPack and raises a stack overflow exception. I've been trying to change the stack size but the solution property window I see only has the options as shown in the screenshot:

[Visual Studio 2013 configuration properties missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329680/visual-studio-2013-configuration-properties-missing)

I've read some other articles which said that C# project's solution property panel's available options are different to that of C++. Where can I configure the stack size of my C# program?

Comment: It is not exposed as an option in the C# compiler, you have to use a [postbuild event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089197/17034).  The odds that this solves your problem are low, SOE is almost always caused by a bug in your program.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a endless loop in your program? (either a standard one from a while not ending or one where recursions don't stop. these are the default causes of stack overflows instead of anything else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the reason behind this is the stack overflow. The issue can be resolved by increasing the stack size.
In visual studio you can do this by using /STACK:reserve[,commit]. [Read the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8cxs58a6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

[For more detailed explanation:](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt)

Under Windows platforms, the stack size information is contained in the executable files. It can be set during compilation in Visual studio C++.
Alternatively, Microsoft provides a program editbin.exe which can change the executable files directly. Here are more details:

**Windows (during compilation):**

```
Select Project->Setting.
Select Link page.
Select Category" to "Output.
Type your preferred stack size in Reserve: field under Stack 
allocations. eg, 32768 in decimal or 0x20000 in hexadecimal.
```

**Windows (to modify the executable file):**

There are two programs included in Microsoft Visual Studio, dumpbin.exe and editbin.exe. Run dumpbin /headers executable_file, and you can see the size of stack reserve information in optional header values. Run editbin /STACK:size to change the default stack size.