# C# code -2147023895 (0x800703e9) while debugging

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm trying to debug some information of my list that is made of objects of a class I made. When I try to check it, it stops debugging and gives the following code in the output window:

> The program <6880> 'MyApp.vshost.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).

When I searched for the number, I found this:

> Recursion too deep; the stack overflowed.

When I read this, it seems to me that I have an infinite loop or something like that.

When I search for this, I get to MSDN and it says contact the supplier. well that's me....

Another topic I found on stackoverflow is this one: [Runtime exception, recursion too deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106708/runtime-exception-recursion-too-deep)

But this is about looping for like .. a really long time.

Mine is just a list with some information saved in it.

This is the class

```
class LinePiece
{
    private string type;
    private string elementNumber;
    private int beginX, beginY;
    private int endX, endY;
    private int diameter;
    private string text;

    public string Type { get { return type; } }
    public string ElementNumber { get { return ElementNumber; } }
    public int BeginX { get { return beginX; } }
    public int BeginY { get { return beginY; } }
    public int EndX { get { return endX; } }
    public int EndY { get { return endY; } }

    public LinePiece(string a_type, string a_eleNr, int a_beginX, int a_beginY, int a_endX, int a_endY)
    {
        type = a_type;
        elementNumber = a_eleNr;
        beginX = a_beginX;
        beginY = a_beginY;
        endX = a_endX;
        endY = a_endY;
    }
}
```

And I create a list like this: `List<LinePiece> l_linePieces = new List<LinePiece>();`

and add a line like this:

```
LinePiece LP = new LinePiece(s_lpType, s_EleNr, i_X1, i_Y1, i_X2, i_Y2);
l_linePieces.Add(LP);
```

When I debug at this point, I click on the `l_linePieces` it displays the amount of objects are in it. But when I try to open one of them, it stops and gives the error.

Also when I don't debug it, it's all fine, it gives no errors etc. But I want to check some values in this list.

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Nicely put.  Made me chuckle thanks.  "Contact the supplier.  well that's me..."

Answer (score 13):

This property getter...

```
public string ElementNumber { get { return ElementNumber; } }
```

...calls itself.

To avoid this in future, you should probably use automatic properties, which look like this:

```
public string ElementNumber { get; set; }
```

The compiler will invent a hidden backing field.

You can initialise the auto properties in your constructor as follows:

```
public LinePiece(string a_type, string a_eleNr,
                 int a_beginX, int a_beginY,
                 int a_endX, int a_endY)
{
    Type = a_type;
    ElementNumber = a_eleNr;
    BeginX = a_beginX;
    BeginY = a_beginY;
    EndX = a_endX;
    EndY = a_endY;
}
```

If you want to set them only from the class itself (i.e. in the constructor), then use `private set`:

```
public string ElementNumber { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Right thats it... working all day on software is sometimes exhausting. you just don't see littlle flaws like this... thx for the help

Comment: @Bart This is where auto-properties can save you some frustration: `public string ElementNumber { get; private set; }`; then you wouldn't need the explicit private field at all (the compiler will create one for you).

Comment: Whats the use of `private set`? when I don't mention set at all it also tells you cant set it.